# IDE other than XCode for IPhone development

Tags: iphone

I have been using **XCode** for *IPhone development* since start. Out of curiosity, are there other IDEs available for *IPhone development*. If so, in what way are they better than **XCode** (if they are). Kindly help me learning with that IDE if there is any.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using tools provided by Adobe.
Check this Link http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html

But as Williham said XCode is the best way there is.

Answer (score 3):

There are no realistic alternatives to XCode for development using Cocoa or Cocoa Touch; i.e. applications targeting Mac OS X or iOS.

Answer (score 1):

My project manager used Mac's TextEdit to code a robust game, game framework and some libraries from scratch. The advantages of TextEdit: Load faster than xcode.

Answer (score 0):

There is [AppCode](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/OBJC/AppCode+EAP;jsessionid=B754C46457B3D1B31E22418C5BF0AE96) by [Jetbrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/). Still in development, though.

Not really for me - but if you're a user of their other IDEs, then you might find it more comfortable than Xcode.